Periodic B-Spline Interpolation
Question on Periodic B-Spline Interpolation :
I'm currently working on a problem involving periodic B-Spline interpolation, and I'm having some difficulties setting up the linear system. I would greatly appreciate any help.
The given setup is as follows:
Consider the uniform partition
$[
\mathcal{T} := \{ [a + (j-1)h, a+jh] : j = 1, \dots, n \}, \quad h := \frac{b-a}{n}
]$
with $( x_j := a + jh )$ representing the $( j )$-th knot $(( j = 1, \dots, n ))$. The associated B-Spline basis is denoted by $( B_{-1}, \dots, B_{n+1} )$. For the computation of the periodic interpolating spline, the function values $( f_0, \dots, f_n )$ are given.
In part (a) of the exercise, we are asked to represent the spline function ( s ) in the following form:
$[
s = \sum_{i=-1}^{n+1} u_i B_i
]$
with $( \mathbf{u} := (u_{-1}, \dots, u_{n+1})^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n+3} )$. We need to set up a linear system to determine $( \mathbf{u} )$ for ( n > 2 ) and ( n = 2 ).
I am able to set up the linear systems for both natural and clamped splines, but I am getting confused with the additional conditions for periodic splines.
My question:
How should I proceed to set up the corresponding linear system? What boundary and periodic conditions need to be considered, especially for the periodic interpolation?
I would be very thankful for a step-by-step guide or hints on constructing the matrix form. Thank you in advance!
$ s'(a) = s'(b), \quad s''(a) = s''(b) \quad \text{with the additional condition } f_0 = f_n \, (\text{periodic spline})$.
